# ¿Porqué no funciona mi bucle FOR en javascript correctamente?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Me pasa algo muy extraño que no le veo sentido.

Tengo un bucle for en javascript que se salta la interación 4 siempre. El código es muy largo, os dejo solo el fragmento donde detecto el error.

Agrego un poco de info:
Tengo una función anterior que va generando inputs de esta forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref_X" value="2" id="ref_X">
<input type="hidden" name="unidades_X" id="uni2_X" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="precio_X" value="3" id="pre2_X">
<input type="hidden" name="id_X" id="id_X" value="9299984">
<input type="hidden" name="nombre_X" id="nombre_X" value="Prueba 2">
<input type="hidden" name="iva_X" id="iva_X" value="21">
```

Donde X es un contador (cada vez que genero el bloque anterior, el contador se incrementa).

Después de crear cada bloque paso al for de abajo que recorre todos los bloques de inputs para guardarlos y actualizar otros datos.

El caso es que el bloque 4 contiene toda la info y no lee el input id="iva_4":

```
<input type="hidden" name="iva_4" id="iva_4" value="21">
```

pero si el resto del mismo bloque 4.

Blucle for:

```
    for(var a=1; a<=contador; a++){
            unidades = document.getElementById('uni2_'+a).value; 
            precio = document.getElementById('pre2_'+a).value; 
            total = parseFloat(total) + (parseFloat(unidades)*parseFloat(precio));
            nombre = document.getElementById('nombre_'+a).value; 
            iva = document.getElementById('iva_'+a).value;

            alert(a+"->"+document.getElementById('iva_'+a).value);//Da undefined
            alert(a+"->"+document.getElementById('nombre_'+a).value);//Si lo muestra
}
```

Y lo que hay realmente en ese momento es:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref_4" value="2" id="ref_4">
<input type="hidden" name="unidades_4" id="uni2_4" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="precio_4" value="3" id="pre2_4">
<input type="hidden" name="id_4" id="id_4" value="9299984">
<input type="hidden" name="nombre_4" id="nombre_4" value="Prueba 2">
<input type="hidden" name="iva_4" id="iva_4" value="21">
```

¿Tiene sentido? El resto de interacciones si las hace correctamente.

PD: Solucionada, tenía otro  con el id="iva_4" ...!!

Comment: te da algun error en la consola ? que tiene que hacer la interacion, osea, cual es su funcion  ?

Comment: La consola no da ningún error, la iteracción recoge los inputs para tratarlos despues. Agrego una explicación un poco más detallada en el post.

Comment: si podes agregar el codigo completo seria mejor, ya que el fragmento de codigo que pusiste funciona perfectamente, seguramente hay algo por detras que te esta dando algun problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu bucle funciona, no tendría por que saltarse el 4, quizás tienes un error en algúna otra parte del código que no has publicado, pero el bucle de la pregunta me funciona:

```
>>> contador = 6;
6
>>> for(var a=1; a<=contador; a++){console.log(a);}
1 debugger eval code:1:32
2 debugger eval code:1:32
3 debugger eval code:1:32
4 debugger eval code:1:32
5 debugger eval code:1:32
6
```

Revisa la consola de desarrollo del navegador y puedes usarla para probar trozos de código que creas dan error, además de las herramientas que tiene para depurar, etc. En la consola deberías tener errores y warnings que serían de ayuda.

EDITO:
Con los cambios añadidos a la pregunta, sigue funcionando, me pongo un elemento HTML como indicas (solo el 4) y usando tu mismo código para acceder al de iva funciona:

```
>>> contador = 6;
6
>>> for(var a=1; a<=contador; a++){console.log(document.getElementById('iva_'+a) ? document.getElementById('iva_'+a).value : null);}
null
null
null
21
null
null
```

EDITO:
Al final el problema era un span con el mismo ID. Seguramente estaba antes, lo encontraba antes y de ese modo realmente no se accedía al input.

Comment: Ya, funciona porque los alerts me los muestra, lo raro es que del input 4, no coja el valor.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que el input 4 no coja el valor? ¿Que en otra parte del código intentas cambiar el value de ese input?

Comment: En ninguna otra, he dado una explicación mas amplia en el primer post.

Comment: Maaadre mia, tenía otro span con el mismo id="iva_4" ....!!

Comment: Entonces era eso, coge el primer elemento que encuentra por ese ID quizás y de ahí el problema.